# Redirect wordpress post : ex, http://test.com/postid to http://test.com/author/postid

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, redirect

Assume I have a website test.com. I have installed wordpress on it. Now I want to redirect http://test.com/postid to http://test.com/author/postid .

Server has nginx + php-fpm . What redirection rule will help me to achieve this?

thanks

Comment: Read the rewrite module - http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html

Comment: This is quite broad. I'd advise on sharing code you've already got and asking a question about it rather than asking for an opinion on a potential direction.